# Local minimum global

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, optimization

Let $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ be continuous. Assume that $f$ has a local minimum at some point $x_0$. Further assume that this is the only point where $f$ has a local extremum. Does it follow that $f$ has a global minimum at $x_0$.
Thanks

Comment: The answer seems to be yes.  Can you show some work you've done on the problem so far, or your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a local extremum uses "soft" ineqaulities. For example for all $x$ in a neigborhood of your $x_0$ we have $f(x) \ge f(x_0)$.

Then the answer to your question would be yes, I think.

We know there is a neighborhood around $x_0$ such that $f(x) \ge f(x_0)$ for $x$ there. Choose a point from in there, $x_1 \ne x_0$, then actually $f(x_1) > f(x_0)$ strictly, because otherwise $f$ would have a local minimum (of the same size) at $x_1$ too.

Now, we want to prove that this minimum at $x_0$ is global. Suppose it was not. Then some $x_\star$ exists with $f(x_\star) < f(x_0)$ strictly. Without loss of generality, $x_\star$ lies on the same side of $x_0$ as does $x_1$. Then look at $f$ restricted to the compact interval between $x_\star$ and $x_0$. The image of this compact interval contains its supremum. In other words $f$ restricted to the compact interval has a maximum. By construction this maximum is attained in the interior of the interval. So there is a local maximum, which contradicts our hypothesis.

Comment: Global minimums also can be allowed to be "soft" (i.e. $f(x_\star)\le f(x_0)$)

Comment: @Squirtle Not sure I understand. If $f(x_\star)=f(x_0)$, then $x_\star$ is no longer a "witness" that the original $x_0$ wasn't global, because as I said in the beginning, extrema are defined with non-strict inequality signs.

Comment: @Squirtle As far as I can see, this proof works no matter if you define extrema using strict or non-strict inequalities? Did you downvote?

Comment: I did downvote, but I have removed it because I see honest effort here and I downvoted based on the hard vs soft and wasn't sure what "witness" was referring to.  I like it, but only have one question.....  I don't like that you are saying, "$f$ restricted to some compact set $[x_\star,x_0]$ obtains a maximum, hence contradiction."  That isn't a contradiction at all, in fact when we say "$f$ obtains only one local extremum", it is implicit that we mean "on all of $(a,b)$".  For example, $f$ restricted to a single point obtains an extremum, but that's obviously no contradiction.  Agreed?

Comment: @Squirtle Yes. The global maximum of the restriction of $f$ to $[x_\star,x_0]$ will, because it falls in the interior of this interval, also be a _local_ maximum for the non-restricted $f$. That is one additional local extremum of our original $f$, and the desired contradiction is reached.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In *one* variable, it is true that a differentiable function with only one local extremum must also have a global extremum at that point. It is not true in *several* variables, however. Intuitively, the reason for this is that a function of one variable can't go from being increasing to being decreasing (or vice versa) without passing through a local extremum; but in several variables, a function can start to decrease in one direction without necessarily decreasing in all other directions. Wikipedia's article on maxima and minima provides this example:
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2(1-x)^3$$
The only critical point is a local minimum at the origin, with $f(0,0)=0$. However, since $f(4,1)=-11$, this is clearly not a global minimum.

Comment: If a function has only one critical point and it has a global minimum, then such a critical point is a global minimum. Your example does not have a global minimum. Proof of my statement: Since it has a global minimum, it is a critical point; hence this unique critical point is also a global minimum. 

On bounded regions, this statement can be changed to something like: if f has only one point satisfying an optimality condition and it has a global minimum, then such a  point satisfying this optimality condition must be the global minimum.

Comment: Remark: the KKT conditions are not always an optimality condition, since it is not satisfied in every point of the bounded and closed region, but the condition "KKT or not-CQ" is actually an optimality condition.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ achieves global minimum over $[a,b]$. Let us assume, by absurd, that the minimizer is $a$. Observe that over $[a,x_0]$ $f$ must assume a maximum, but this maximum cannot be $x_0$ nor $a$; otherwise, the function would be locally constant around $x_0$ or $a$, but it cannot be the case, since the function can only have one local extremum over $(a,b)$. Observe that the maximum over $[a,x_0]$ is a local extremum over $(a,b)$, and this local extremum would need to be $x_0$, but this is absurd. Hence, the global minimizer cannot be $a$. The case when, by absurd, $b$ is the global minimizer over $[a,b]$ is similar. So the global minimizer over $[a,b]$ can't be $a$ and $b$. Now, when the global minimizer over $[a,b]$ belongs to $(a,b)$, we would need such a point to be a local extremum, and this local extremum must be $x_0$, by your assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

Let's try this again more carefully. (I'll eventually get it right.)

Assume, by way of contradiction, that $x_0$ is not a global minimum. So there exists $x_1 \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_0) > f(x_1)$. WLOG, we may assume that $x_0 < x_1$. Since $x_0$ is a local minimum, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $x\in(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ we have $f(x) \geq f(x_0)$. Then we can take the interval $[x_0,x_1]$, which is compact, and consider the image under $f$. Since $f$ in continuous, there must be a local maximum and a local minimum in the interval. Since $f(x_0) > f(x_1)$, $x_0$ is not the local minimum. Since there is some $x_2 \in (x_0, x+\varepsilon) \subset [x_0,x_1]$ with $f(x_2) \geq f(x_0)$, $x_0$ is not the local maximum. Hence one of the local extrema occurs in the interval $(x_0,x_1)$. But this gives a contradiction since it implies there is a second local extremum. Therefore $x_0$ is a global minimum.

Comment: I don't understand. Your function has the global minimum at 2.

Comment: I agree with @twinky see: [Plot in WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x^3-2*x^2-4*x%2B8+from+1+to+3)

Comment: My mistake. I got myself confused by looking for a function that had no global min on $\mathbb{R}$ and then restricting to meet interval conditions and forgot that changed the function.

Comment: Your answer.... isn't an answer at all, "
EDIT: Previous counterexample was badly formed. Reconsidering problem now."

Comment: I know. I was removing the poorly formed example and attempting to fix it on the spot. Though I seem to have run into the same problem you call ChrisBln out for. Will continue looking at this. Analysis was never my strongest subject.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If it wasn't the global minimum, there would have to be some $x_1\in(a,b)$ s.t. $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$. Now, $[x_1,x_0]$ (or $[x_0,x_1]$) is compact and a continuous function must take a minimum and a maximum on this interval. As the maximum can neither be $x_0$ nor $x_1$, it must be in the interior of the interval and thus would also be a local maximum for f on $(a,b)$ which contradicts your assumption that $f$ didn't have any other local extremal points.

Comment: You have a subtle but important fallacy... namely, you are assuming a minimum $x_0$ cannot be a maximum.

Comment: @Squirtle No, that can be dealt with, can't it? See my answer (which is really the same as this one, only mine is more clumpsy).

Comment: If it were, the function would haver to be locally constant and $x_0$ would not be the only local extremum any more.

Comment: If you are going to answer something... don't have any holes in it, rather than racing to be the first to give an answer with holes in it... consider all possible mistakes.  For example, include "local extremum" argument.

Answer (score -1):

If it was not a global minimum, then there exists a $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$, so it would be a local minimum against the hypothesis that $x_0$ is the only one.

Comment: No. $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$ does not imply that $f$ has a local minimum at $x_1$. Indeed, $f$ needn't have any other local minima.

Comment: If $f(x_1) \to \infty$ we don't consider this a minimum because we can't identity a single point that obtains this minimum especially because $(a,b)$ is an open set.

Comment: @ChrisBln, I believe this is incorrect: You have to consider continuitiy

Comment: @Squirtle, please note that $x_1$ lies in the domain of $f$

Comment: Even a continuous function on an open interval could tend to infinity at the borders.

Comment: @ChrisBln, I had considered such a case, but note this: If we have a similar situation, could the condition of uniqueness of local minimum be relaxed?

Comment: To give an explicit example of what @ChrisBln mentioned in his first comment, with $f(x)=x^2-x^4$ and $(a,b)=(-2,2)$ (see [graph](http://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=x%5E2-x%5E4&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-2&x_max=2&y_min=-14&y_max=1&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525)), the function has only one local minimum, at zero. There are local maxima, however.

Comment: but if domain can be split in some way then, trivially, there are countless examples in support of the fact that you can not deduct the globality of the minimum

Comment: but the domain is (a,b) which is something continuous, so the answer.....

Comment: @ChrsBln, but if this is the case then there must be more *extrema* than one...